# AWS Glue - An error occurred while calling o95.getDynamicFrame. Communications link failure

Tags: amazon-web-services, debugging, etl, aws-glue, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to connect to an external MariaDB database instance using a AWS Glue Spark script and a JDBC Glue connection.

The code snippet from the Spark script is:

```
dyf = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options( 
connection_type = 'mysql', connection_options = 
{ 
 "useConnectionProperties": "true",
 "connectionName": "sample_con_name",
 "dbtable": "admins",
 "customJdbcDriverS3Path": "s3://path_to_connector/mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar",
 "customJdbcDriverClassName": "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"
 } 
)
```

The error that I'm getting after running the Glue Spark job is: **An error occurred while calling o95.getDynamicFrame. Communications link failure**

The Glue connection is based on a private subnet in my VPC. The private subnet has a route through a NAT gateway in my VPC and an elastic IP is attached to the NAT gateway - this elastic IP is already whitelisted by the external DB's admins.

How do I fix this issue? Is it a driver/certificate issue?

Thanks!

Just for testing, I made a EC2 instance on the same private subnet, and wrote a small PHP script to connect to the same external database, and it was connecting successfully.